# 18.04 Virtual Keyboard is QWERTY or AZERTY?

Tags: 18.04, keyboard

How do I know if my virtual keyboard is in [QWERTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY) or [AZERTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY)? Is there a command line I can use to verify that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let's follow the instructions from GNOME, the developers of the On Screen Keyboard for 18.04:

[Summon the virtual keyboard](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/keyboard-osk.html.en) by:

Open the [Activities](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-introduction.html.en#activities) overview and start typing Settings.

Click on Settings.

Click Universal Access in the sidebar to open the panel.

[image]

Switch on the Screen Keyboard in the Typing section and look at the top row. If the first six letters of the top letter row are AZERTY, it's [AZERTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY), which is the default for French and Flemish speakers based in Europe.

Further documentation is found at http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/keyboard.5.html and https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/input/XKB-Config.html

Comment: Not sure to follow you. I added a picture in my question. Can you develop a bit more?

Comment: Can you add a picture? I can't see what you mean again

Comment: I can't see what you mean right now

Comment: I know that, but I can't see the what you mean by "at the top row". Except now I can write with a virtual keyboard instead of my true keyboard. I will change the picture in a minute

Comment: Sorry, wrong picture. Let me change that. The ON and OFF changed nothing for me.

Comment: Then you have a system installation problem. Boot from a LiveUSB made with Ubuntu and use the same sequence to turn the onscreen keyboard ON.

Comment: This is for Ubuntu 19.10, not for Ubuntu 18.04. Go look at the link you posted in your answer

Comment: replaced the instructions and link with a link direct from GNOME the developers of the On Screen Keyboard for 18.04.

Comment: I would like to believe you, but I can't see what you mean at all. I tested your answer on my two computer and I still can't see what you mean. It might help if you can add some pictures

Answer (score 0):

1.Enter settings

2.Go to region & language

you will see under input sources a list of all input languages.
next to every input language you will see an eye icon. Click on it and the layout will appear.